# How to use the minimum date from three available - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to plug a formula into a query to pull back how much should have run on a particular contract.

The formula itself is quite simple, but I can't find anywhere how to take the minimum date between 3, based on each record separately.

I need to calculate which is the earliest of `Term_date`, `Suspend_date` and **today's date**, some of which may be `NULL`, on each contract.

Comment: Plz add the sample data and desired O/P

Comment: Not exactly sure on the query etc, but you could try a case when, like `CASE WHEN Term_date < Suspend_date AND Term_date < GetDate() THEN Term_date WHEN Suspend_date < GetDate() THEN Suspend_date ELSE GetDate() END AS DateInfo`

Answer (score 3):

And interesting way to approach this is to use `cross apply`:

```
select t.contractid, mindte
from table t cross apply
     (select min(dte) as mindte
      from (values(t.term_date), (t.suspend_date), (getdate())) d(dte)
     ) d;
```

Comment: I like that. Cleaner than my CTE approach. Although conceptually a bit trickier.

Answer (score 2):

```
CASE 
    WHEN Term_date < Suspend_date AND Term_date < GETDATE() THEN Term_date
    WHEN Suspend_date < GETDATE() THEN Suspend_date
    ELSE GETDATE()
END AS MinimumDate
```

Comment: Ah... you beat me to it

Comment: I've tried to take this but it says Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'. 

Is 'CASE' specific to a version of SQL-Server? I'm using 2014

Comment: My example should be used in the SELECT-part of a query, as in: `SELECT CASE ... END AS MinimumDate FROM MyTable`

Answer (score 0):

I know a CASE statement will be suggested, but I thought I'd try something different:

```
;WITH cte (RecordID, CheckDate) AS
( SELECT RecordID, Term_date FROM sourcetable UNION ALL
  SELECT RecordID, Suspend_date FROM sourcetable UNION ALL
  SELECT RecordID, GETDATE() FROM sourcetable )
SELECT src.RecordID, src.Field1, src.Field2, MinDate = MIN(cte.CheckDate)
FROM sourcetable src
LEFT JOIN cte ON cte.RecordID = src.RecordID
GROUP BY src.RecordID, src.Field1, src.Field2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `cross apply` to generate a work table from which you can get the minimum date:

```
-- mock table with sample testing data
declare @MyTable table
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    term_date datetime null,
    suspend_date datetime null
)
insert into @MyTable (term_date, suspend_date)
select null, null
union all select '1/1/2015', null
union all select null, '1/2/2015'
union all select '1/3/2015', '1/3/2015'
union all select '1/4/2015', '1/5/2015'
union all select '1/6/2015', '1/5/2015'

select * from @MyTable

select datevalues.id, min([date])
from @MyTable
cross apply
(
    values (id, term_date), (id, suspend_date), (id, getdate())
) datevalues(id, [date])
group by datevalues.id
```